# Запрет движения контента сайта при раскрытом меню

Tags: jquery, меню, javascript

Добрый день! У меня такая проблема возникла, есть меню http://www.rudebox.org.ua/create-side-menus-quickly-with-jquery-sidr/ этот шаблон я внедрил в свой сайт, но возникла проблема в мобильном варианте когда открываешь данное меню, остается краюшек контента который можно без проблем двигать пальцем даже при открытом меню, что есть не очень хорошо. Так у меня вопрос, может кто подскажет как запретить движение контекта при открытом боковом меню? Или дайте ссылки на аналогичные меню (с исходником простым или демо-примером), где такое не наблюдается на мобильных устройствах.

[image]

Comment: самое простое - накрыть контент прозрачным оверлеем (дивом), тап по которому будет закрывать меню.

Comment: Как вариант (*на мой взгляд чуть хуже, чем предложил @Yura Ivanov*) - это для мобильных устройств, делать ширину менюшки, равную ширине окна.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, @Deonis, если накрывать контент дивом или делать ширину менюшки равную ширине окна, то я просто не смогу вернуться потом на свою страницу после раскрытия меню. Должен быть другой способ...

Comment: по тапу/клику/слайду влево на этот div закрывайте меню.

Comment: @IntegralAL, а сейчас как вы возвращаетесь на свою страницу после раскрытия меню? другой способ [pointer-events:none](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) для контента, т.е. для видимых элементов.